# Python.- fuzzy.DMetaphone 'ascii' error

Tags: python, fuzzy, fuzzywuzzy

How is that possible, that with the same input I sometime get `ascii codec` error, and sometime it works just fine? The code cleans the name and build it's `Soundex` and `DMetaphone` values. It works in ~1 out of 5 runs, sometimes more often :)

**UPD:** Looks like that's an issue of `fuzzy.DMetaphone`, at least on Python2.7 with Unicode. Plan to integrate [Metaphone](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Metaphone/0.4) instead, for now. All solutions for `fuzzy.DMetaphone` problem are very welcome :)

**UPD 2:** Problem is gone after `fuzzy` update to 1.2.2. The same code works fine.

```
import re
import fuzzy
import sys

def make_namecard(full_name):
    soundex = fuzzy.Soundex(4)
    dmeta = fuzzy.DMetaphone(4)
    names = process_name(full_name)
    print names
    soundexes = map(soundex, names)
    dmetas = []
    for name in names:
        print name
        dmetas.extend(list(dmeta(name)))
    dmetas = filter(bool, dmetas)

    return {
        "full_name": full_name,
        "soundex": soundexes,
        "dmeta": dmetas,
        "names": names,
    }

def process_name(full_name):
    full_name = re.sub("[_-]", " ", full_name)
    full_name = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]', "", full_name)
    names = full_name.split()
    names = filter(valid_name, names)
    return names

def valid_name(name):
    COMMON_WORDS = ["the", "of"]
    return len(name) >= 2 and name.lower() not in COMMON_WORDS

print make_namecard('Jerusalem Warriors')
```

Output:

```
➜ python2.7 make_namecard.py
['Jerusalem', 'Warriors']
Jerusalem
Warriors
{'soundex': [u'J624', u'W624'], 'dmeta': [u'\x00\x00\x00\x00', u'ARSL', u'ARRS', u'FRRS'], 'full_name': 'Jerusalem Warriors', 'names': ['Jerusalem', 'Warriors']}

➜ python2.7 make_namecard.py
['Jerusalem', 'Warriors']
Jerusalem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_namecard.py", line 38, in <module>
    print make_namecard('Jerusalem Warriors') 
  File "make_namecard.py", line 16, in make_namecard
    dmetas.extend(list(dmeta(name)))
  File "src/fuzzy.pyx", line 258, in fuzzy.DMetaphone.__call__
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xab in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Noone's going to be able to help debug your code without reading it

Comment: What version of `fuzzy` are you using?